# How to create a linked list with a void function?

Tags: c

So I want to know would I make a linked-list using a void function. So I would have a struct

```
typedef struct linked{
  int i;
  struct linked *next;
}linked;
```

with the node starting as

```
linked *head = NULL;
```

and I want to create it with a function

```
void createLL(linked *head, int i)
```

I am familiar with the way of using

```
linked *createLL(linked *head, int i)
```

but I am curious on how would it be done with a void function.

Comment: And why would one wanted to use a hammer to put in a screw?

Comment: @Olaf It's for a class assignment, so I don't have much of a choice.

Comment: That's a stupid constraint. You should learn how to write good code, not nonsense code. Feel free to cite me:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass head in as a pointer to a pointer:

```
void createLL(linked** head, int i)
{
    linked* pNewHead = (linked*)malloc(sizeof(linked));
    pNewHead->i = i;
    *head = pNewHead;
}
```

Then to invoke:

```
linked* head = NULL;
createLL(&head);
```

Comment: how would I check if the head is empty as its a double *. Would it be `if((*head) == NULL)`?

Comment: If you're checking in the function, yes. You don't need the parenthesis around `*head`.